# Modify card into viewpager fragment from activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

i have this situation:

OffersActivity which contain a viewpgageradapter where into there are 3 fragment:

- offers, all offers and bio offers.

These fragment contain a material card with days offers about food.

When you click on the card, another activity is calling ( addproduct), where you can order the food.

When you finish, you return to previus Offers Activity which contain the fragment.

My goals is set a background color of specific card when the user order food in add product activity

The question is : how i get the view of fragment  and modify the card from activity ?

Comment: Hi ! It would be better if you checkout [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code for future endeavor at Stack overflow. -Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There's a method called **[setCardBackgroundColor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html?hl=es#setCardBackgroundColor(int))** which updates the background color of the cardView. It represents color as 4 byte integer in the format [ARGB](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html?hl=es#argb(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)). You can use `Color.argb(int alpha, int red, int green, int blue);`

Comment: Ok but the problem is: how i get the view from fragment in viewpager and modify the card?